# ¿Cómo puedo quitar los primeros N caracteres de un fichero con Sed?

Tags: sed

Necesito modificar el contenido de los siguientes archivos.

La meta es quitar la primer columna, y parte de la segunda desde la posición 0 hasta la posición 43.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quedando de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
sed -i 's/^.{43}//' $file
```

pero no sé si servirá.

Comment: sed es un programa y no es limitado a Bash, debe funcionar en qualquier shell.

Comment: Sería mejor que proporcionaras un [mcve] en texto, no con imágenes. Así podremos replicar lo que intentaste de forma mucho más fácil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que tienes de sed es prácticamente correcto. Deberías usar:

```
sed -r 's/^.{43}//' fichero
```

Nótese que `-r` es para que `.{43}` se interprete correctamente, es decir, "43 caracteres cualquiera" y no como la cadena literal "{43}".

También puedes explicarle esto al sed normal sin `-r` escapando las llaves:

```
sed 's/^.\{43\}//' fichero
```

Ejemplo quitando los primeros 4 caracteres:

```
$ cat b
1234567890
$ sed 's/^.\{4\}//' b
567890
$ sed -r 's/^.{4}//' b
567890
```

Fíjate también que estás utilizando `-i`, que modifica el fichero. Conviene que lo uses una vez estés seguro de que está funcionando y, además, es sugerible que le añadas una extensión para que te genere un fichero de backup:

```
sed -r -i.bak 's/^.{43}//' fichero
```