# ¿Cómo elimino todo el texto de una línea a partir de un carácter?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, shell-script, sed

Estoy buscando la manera de eliminar cierto contenido de diferentes líneas dentro de un script ( Ubuntu )

Si tengo por ejemplo:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.52.69.98.25 = Problema123
```

Mi idea es eliminar todo a partir del "=" incluyéndolo. ( Borrar ' = Problema123' de manera que quede "1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.52.69.98.25 " solamente)

Lo he intentado con el comando *sed*, pero no me ha salido, no sé si se me escapa algún parámetro o si es otro diferente.

```
sed -e 's/^.//' -e 's/.$//'
```

o

```
sed -r 's/.* = (.*)/\1/'
```

Este ultimo comando hace lo contrario, borrar todo antes del '='

Comment: ¿Podrías detallar un poco más la lógica? ¿Dado algo tipo `nu.me.ros palabra = numero` quieres dejar solamente `palabra`? ¿Todas las líneas son así? ¿`palabra` no tiene espacios? Proporciona un [mcve] así como qué querías que hiciera cada comando de sed y por qué no funciona.

Comment: Edité el post, a ver si así queda un poco mas claro, quiero eliminar la parte final de la línea, el fichero tiene múltiples líneas pero siguiendo el mismo patrón. @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'

Comment: Ajá, ahora se ve mejor. ¿y todas las líneas son así? ¿O qué hay que hacer con las que no lo son?

Comment: Todas las líneas siguen el mismo patrón, solo cambian los números iniciales, de ahí que solo quiera borrar  del '= hacia adelante. @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'

Comment: Vale. Ojo que a veces dices a partir de "=" pero en el ejemplo no sé si quieres cargarte también el espacio que va antes

Comment: Efectivamente, quiero cargarme ese espacio también.         
sed '/=/s/ =.*//' fichero
Esta sirvió

Comment: Fantástico, fíjate que al poner `/=/` delante le estoy diciendo que solo lo haga en las líneas que contienen este carácter (de hecho es redundante).

Comment: Todo funciono como quería pero crees que es posible hacer lo siguiente; eliminar todo lo anterior al numero 17  @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'

Comment: Encontré la respuesta en otro post tuyo
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/188516/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-quitar-los-primeros-n-caracteres-de-un-fichero-con-sed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres eliminar todo a partir del carácter "=" y hasta el final de la línea, puedes usar Sed con:

```
sed '/=/s/=.*//' fichero
```

Esto hará que sustituya desde "=" y hasta el final por la cadena vacía. Es decir, que lo borra.

De todos modos, si todas las líneas son del mismo tipo, puedes ir por algo más directo como Cut o Awk:

```
cut -d'=' -f1 fichero
```

Esto define el delimitador como "=" e imprime el primer "trozo".

```
awk -F= '{print $1}' fichero
```

Equivalentemente, con Awk le decimos que el separador de campos es "=" y que imprima el primero.

Comment: Funciono a la perfección, Moltes Gràcies